# How many continuous functions exist such that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)(1 − f(x))dx = \frac{1}4$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, definite-integrals, continuity

> **QUESTION:**  Let $f : \Bbb{R} → \Bbb{R}$. Answer whether the following are true (T) or false (F).

> > $(a)$ There is no continuous function $f$ for which $$\int_{0}^{1}
> > f(x)(1 − f(x))dx < \frac{1}4$$

---

> > $(b)$ There is only one continuous function $f$ for which $$\int_{0}^{1}
> > f(x)(1 − f(x))dx = \frac{1}4$$

---

> > $(c)$ There are infinitely many continuous functions $f$ for which $$\int_{0}^{1}
> > f(x)(1−f(x))dx = \frac{1}4$$

---

**MY WORKING:**

For the first one I have observed that if we put $f(x)=x^n$ for any $n\in \Bbb{N}$ then the definite integral reduces to $\frac{1}6$.

Therefore there are infinitely many functions which satisfy the first statement, which makes it false (F).

Now from the second one onwards, I could not do much.. I was just wondering about a general way to solve these kind of problems.. What I did for $(a)$ is just assume a function, but I know, that is not a rigorous proof.

Can anyone tell me some good method to solve these problems without assuming functions.. And also, there are infinite number of functions all around, so that method is a very very tiresome and illogical thing to do..

Thank you so much for your kind help and support :)

Comment: @Martin R... No I have seen that.. That and mine are different.. although given the same title.. you may have a look.. :)

Comment: If you are aware of a similar question then it is a good idea to mention that in your question, and explain how your problem is different.

Comment: @StrangerForever please explain how this question is not a duplicate of the suggested question.

Comment: When $f(x)=x^n$, the value of the definite integral depends on $n$, and doesn't equal $\frac16$ when $n>1$.

Comment: What is the maximum value of $t(1-t)$ for any real number $t$? Hence what is the maximum value of $f(x)(1-f(x))$?